# SQL foreign key Constraint in DBMS

Tags: sql

If my DBMS does not implement foreign key constraint, what can I do to express a foreign key constraint rather that a view (to insert to with check option)?

Comment: What is your DBMS?  That would make it easier for us to help if that were known.

Comment: Are you asking for MySQL, SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: No theoretically, not for an actual DBMS , i want to know if there is an other way other than Views

Comment: db enforced referential integrity with a view, how does that work?

Comment: What features does your theoretical database have?

Comment: @DCookie that was good. Took a while to stop laughing

Comment: Upgrade to a modern DBMS that supports foreign keys

Comment: Is this an interview question to see how you would solve a particular problem?

Comment: Exactly, i only know to solve that with Views ( MySQL views with a check option ) but is there an other solution ????